# Why does my Streamlit application open multiple times?

Tags: python, operating-system, streamlit

I am trying to start the Streamlit application using

```
import os
os.popen("streamlit run stockXchange.py")
```

When I run this code, there will be an infinite number of streamlit windows, popping up one after another every 3 or so seconds. The only way to stop these windows from popping up is by closing the output window completely. (I am using PyCharm)

Here is my code:

```
import os
import streamlit as st
class Streamlit:


    def __init__(self):
        Streamlit.setup()


    def setup(self):
        st.title("StockXchange GUI")
        query = st.text_input("Enter company name:")
        if st.button("Go"):
            #calls the application function
            load(query)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(starttext)
    print(os.popen("streamlit run stockXchange.py").read())
    #Workaround 'missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'' Error
    Streamlit.setup(Streamlit)
```

I want there to only be one window popping up,  not an infinite number of windows.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Streamlit you don't need to create a class wrapper to run your Streamlit application.

Presuming that your `stockXchange.py` is the streamlit app, then it should be run from the command line or [from the PyCharm console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-console.html) like so:

```
streamlit run stockXchange.py
```

All of the following lines from your class should go into that file:

```
st.title("StockXchange GUI")
query = st.text_input("Enter company name:")
if st.button("Go"):
    #the rest of stockXchange.py pertaining to the query
```

The reason you're getting unlimited streamlit windows is that the following line creates an infinite loop in terms of program execution:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.popen("streamlit run stockXchange.py")
```